# Python script freezes randomly

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.7 (64 Bit) on windows 10. My script works well, it just freezes sometimes during writing to the database. Sometimes it writes over 100k rows, sometimes it freezes at 5000 or something like that. It is just randomly and i don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
from math import log2
import time

corporaDb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="root"
)
dictionaryDb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="root",
    database="dictionaries"
)
dictionaryDatabaseName = "dictionaries"
corpus = "deu_news_2015"

corporaCursor = corporaDb.cursor()
dictionaryCursor = dictionaryDb.cursor()

lang = corpus[:3]
print(lang)
print(datetime.datetime.now().time())
query = "SELECT freq FROM "+corpus+".words order by freq desc LIMIT 1"
corporaCursor.execute(query)
freqMax= corporaCursor.fetchone()
freqMax = freqMax[0]


query = "SELECT w.freq, t.translation_id FROM "+dictionaryDatabaseName+".word_translations t INNER JOIN "+corpus+".words w ON t.translation = w.word where target_language = '"+lang+"' LIMIT 2700000, 2000000"
corporaCursor.execute(query)
result = corporaCursor.fetchall();
i= 0
for row in result:
    if(i % 1000 == 0):
        print(i)
    if(row[0] != "None"):
        try: 
            frequencyClass = round(log2(freqMax/row[0]))
            query = "UPDATE word_translations SET freq = "+str(row[0])+", available = 1, freq_class = "+str(frequencyClass)+" WHERE translation_id = '"+str(row[1])+"'"
            dictionaryCursor.execute(query)
            if(i % 100 == 0):
                dictionaryDb.commit()
        except:
            dictionaryCursor.close()
            print ("fehler")
            time.sleep(30)
            dictionaryCursor = dictionaryDb.cursor()
            pass
    i+=1

corporaDb.close()
```

Comment: If both database servers are on localhost, you could try exporting one into a file and reading from it. Or you could try doing reads & writes in batches.

Comment: I don't know MySQL, but I'd expect this to go a lot faster if you did this "inside" the database.  i.e. I think you should be able to do all this with a single `UPDATE` query (maybe with a CTE)

Comment: they are not both on localhost, i just added this data to not show my real config. Exporting is not possible because the databases are to big. It is also not possible to do it with a single update query because of the calculation of the frequencyClass